# ARIA attributes not working with Material UI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, wai-aria

I am trying to pass the aria attribute `aria-current` to the Material UI component `<ListItem>`.

```
<ListItem
 aria-current={href === location.pathname ? 'page' : ''}
 aria-label={href === location.pathname ? 'page' : ''}
 component={RouterLink}
 data-testid={dataTestId}
 key={href}
 role='menuitem'
 selected={href === location.pathname}
 sx={listItemStyle}
 to={href}
>
```

The `aria-label` attribute works fine, but `aria-current` does not.  I get the following error when trying to do so:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in src/components/NavBar/NavBar.tsx:58:13

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; "aria-current": "" | "page"; "aria-label": string; component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<LinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>>; ... 5 more ...; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { button?: false | undefined; } & ListItemBaseProps & { components?: { Root?: ElementType<any> | undefined; } | undefined; componentsProps?: { ...; } | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { button?: false | undefined; } & ListItemBaseProps & { components?: { Root?: ElementType<any> | undefined; } | undefined; componentsProps?: { ...; } | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'. Did you mean 'components'?
    56 |             aria-current={href === location.pathname ? 'page' : ''}
    57 |             aria-label={href === location.pathname ? 'page' : ''} // TODO: Figure out aria-current fix
  > 58 |             component={RouterLink}
       |             ^^^^^^^^^
    59 |             data-testid={dataTestId}
    60 |             key={href}
    61 |             role='menuitem'
```

When removing the `aria-current` line, the code runs with no errors, but when adding it, it complains about the `component` attribute that runs fine without it.  I thought it would be safe to pass any ARIA attributes, but it appears otherwise.